# Attempt to de-reference a null object in fieldset

Tags: visualforce, fieldsets

I am trying to get fields from Contact into fieldset. but i am not bale to get the fields properly i am getting error : Attempt to de-reference a null object

my code :

```
     public class DemoCtrl{

     public contact DemoCtrl { get; set; }

     public List<schema.fieldsetmember> getACTFields(){ 
             // System.debug('getField ' + Fields);     
             return getFields('contact', 'ACT');
     }


       public static List<schema.fieldsetmember> getFields(String objectName, String fieldSetName) 
      {  

        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> GlobalDescribeMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
        Schema.SObjectType SObjectTypeObj = GlobalDescribeMap.get(objectName);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult DescribeSObjectResultObj = SObjectTypeObj.getDescribe();            
         Schema.FieldSet fieldSetObj = DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets.getMap().get(fieldSetName);
         //DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets.getMap().get(fieldSetName);        


          System.debug('GlobalDescribeMap ' + GlobalDescribeMap);
         System.debug(' SObjectTypeObj  ' + SObjectTypeObj );
          System.debug('DescribeSObjectResultObj ' +          DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets.getMap().get(fieldSetName)); 
         System.debug('fieldSetObj  ' + fieldSetObj ); 
        return fieldSetObj.getFields();        


     }      

   }
```

I am getting null into DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets.getMap().get(fieldSetName).
Can anybody guide me what is the issue it is not getting filled.

Comment: Either `DescribeSObjectResultObj` is null, or it doesn't contain fieldsets, making `DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets` null. Can you put them in a `System.Debug` call?

Comment: the DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSetsFieldSets is through --> DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSetsFieldSets[Contact] in System.debug. And DescribeSObjectResultObj through --> contact

Comment: Your code worked for me. Seems like the API name of your field set is not ACT.

Comment: Can anybody tell me how to save the entered value into the object. I want to use a custom button on it.

Comment: yes, you are right. I have solved it. can  you tell me how to save the entered value into the object. I want to use a custom button on it

Comment: can you elaborate, i did not completely understand what you are trying to say. Do you mean that you are using fieldsets on the vf page and then you want to save data enetred by the user on that page?

Comment: excataly you understood right

Comment: you do it the same way its done while saving the records on a normal vf page which takes input from the user. in your case, DemoCtrl (which is of type "Contact"); you need to write insert DemoCtrl/update DemoCtrl depending upon the operation you wish to perform.

And in case you are using the standard controller as Contact, i gues simply <apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/> should also work.

Comment: yes i am using <apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/> but it is asking to create a save() in controller

Comment: what i did is I created a method in the controller and wrote the below code: public PageReference SaveRec() { upsert contact; PageReference pr = new PageReference('/'+contact.Id); return pr; } and the action method of the command button is "{!SaveRec}"

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me. Like,

DemoCtrl.getFields('Contact', 'FieldSet_Name');

But if you use Field Label of FieldSet in the call, you will get the error.

By any chance, have your used a label name but not the API name to call your field set?

Comment: can you tell me how to save the entered value into the object. I want to use a custom button on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a System.debug on the fieldsetName and verify if the field set Name is correct, you may be able to find out the problem.

Comment: yes that i did it is getting -- > ACT